# .Net Framework documentation location

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

im working on a documentation project and i need to parse the .net framework documentation.
I want to use NDoc for that. I have successfully installed the .net framework and the msdn library. The problem is that i am not able to find the dll's and there corresponding xml files. I'm even not sure if they exists or if the documentation browser uses compiled helpfiles.

To make it short: What is the location of the .net framework dll's and there corresponding .xml documentation files (if those exists).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my system they can be found at (.dll and .xml)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\
```

and (.dll only)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 4):

On my machine, they live here:

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<FrameworkVersion>\en\
```

They might also be alongside the DLLs in

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<FrameworkVersion>
```

**UPDATE:**
It appears as if one part of the files lies in the folders I specified above and another part - specifically WPF - lies in the folder specified by Dennis. See [this question in the Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/a3da6655-0fa6-47f9-adb8-ff8943a24d48/) for some official confirmation.

Comment: I don't see the XML files there on mine, wonder if it changes install to install?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Possibly

Comment: [This link](http://forums.reflector.net/questions/124/is-it-possible-to-see-xml-documentation-for-members-and-types) proves my point.

Comment: Good find, appears the Framework64 directories lack them (hence my 404 problem).

Answer (score 0):

Framework DLLs, at least for the most part, are in the Global Assembly Cache. This is primarily a percompile for performance step. You will find copies under %WINDIR%/Microsoft .NET/{framework version}.

The default location for local help is C:\Program Data\Microsoft\HelpLibrary\

Comment: `Program Data`? I've got local help installed to its default location, and it's not there.

Comment: One thing you can try is Start >> All Programs >> Visual Studio 2010 >> Visual Studio Tools >> Manage Help Settings - ENU. If it asks for a location, you are probably not set up correctly. Once in the tool click Choose online or local help. At the bottom, you will have the "library location" in a disabled textbox.

Comment: The default location depends on your version of Windows evidently.

Comment: That would not surprise me. Did you find the location using the steps above?

Comment: My Win7 machine has it under another drive/folder, as it appears my `%PROGRAMDATA%` is redirected on my work machine. My XP machine has it under `Documents and Settings`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out %PROGRAMDATA%, as that is a good shortcut to finding the location of the help directory, which I assume, for you, is %PROGRAMDATA%/Microsoft/HelpLibrary, which corresponds to (Documents and Settings folder)/Microsoft/HelpLibrary. I use the %WINDIR% pointer a lot, but did not know the %PROGRAMDATA% pointer existed. Another piece of info to note and regurgitate later. ;-)

Answer (score -3):

XML is not stored on disk and dll's could be found under system GAC. Why do you need to document entire .net framework library?

Comment: Guide me where it is stored? And what is the purpose of keeping xml file on user machine? To create MSDN?

Comment: I don't see xml on my machine for 2+ versions. For 2 i can see 49 xml files out of which I dont see assemblies I use very commonly.

Comment: I still don't agree. Probably u might have because of msdn installed with local help. I can't find on my system. I don't see reason why it has to be on user machine.

Comment: Please check the update to my answer. That you don't find it useful to have these XML files is pretty strange. **I find them useful, because otherwise IntelliSense wouldn't be able to display the documentation for the .NET frameworks methods, classes, etc.**

Comment: Are you sure intellisense shows details from xml file? How about my own classes with comments? Comments on my class wont appear if I don't save my xml file in that folder. What about third party libraries?